# html form with optgroups doesn't change size

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a very long `<form>`, shown here http://jsfiddle.net/L6j7P/ - why does the form only show one `<optgroup>` at a time when the child elements are not displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove the option display:none

```
option {display:none;}  /* remove this */
```

Comment: I'm working on making the `<optgroup>` collapsible, so it is `display:none;` by default. Basically I want to show all of the `<optgroup>s` without having to scroll.